# Going from one viewController to another on a different Tab

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making a dummy app to study the how to transition from one ViewController to another when they do not have anything connecting them.

I have a TabBar controller based application which has 3 tabs. Each tab has a child viewController. Each child viewController has two buttons which are suppose to take the user to one of the other two viewControllers. Eg - The first viewController has a child viewController, which has two buttons. Button 1 is for going to child ViewController of the viewController connected to Tab 2 and the Button 2 is for going to child ViewController of the viewController connected to Tab 3.

[image]

I am having hard time implementing this program. Can somebody give me some suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit 1:

Reason:

Imagine an app in there are two tabs, one which displays thumbnails of the pictures that have been taken and the other which activates the camera. Once the user clicks the image, the app should takes the user to the tab which displays the thumbnails of all the images. Forget the UI aspect of the app for a moment. How do I accomplish what has been described above?

Answer (score 2):

Don't switch tabs for a user.  It violates the principle of a tab bar controller.

If you want to transition between controllers WITHIN a tab, use a UINavigationController as the root view controller in the tab, and then push/pop as normal.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where can I review the rules and regulations? I am just making an edit to explain the reason why I am doing this.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH1-SW1

Comment: thanks.. taking a look at the moment.. pls refer to my edit in the mean time.

Comment: i referred to the link for [TabBarController] (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW520) , But I did not find anything that says I cannot change the tab for the user.

Comment: OK, I guess it's not forbidden any more, I did think it was in there at one point.  To change it you just changed the selectedIndex property on the tab bar controller.